# Converter e salvar foto em BD

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc-5, winforms, processamento-de-imagens

Estou trabalhando em um projeto onde tenho que salvar algumas fotos. Então estou estudando a melhor maneira para realizar a tarefa.

Pensei em salvar no banco de dados, pois essas fotos serão acessadas tanto localmente (aplicação WinForms) como via internet (Aplicação MVC Asp.Net).

Então achei uma solução que consiste em transformar a foto em um `Array` de `Byte`, conforme o código abaixo:

```
MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();

meuPictureBox1.Image.Save(stream, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);

byte[] foto = stream.ToArray();
```

E então salvar no banco de dados, onde a tabela tem as seguintes características:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Crm_Fotos]
    (
    [id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [nCrm] [int] NULL,
    [Bfoto] [image] NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
    (
```

Porém, estou com algumas dúvidas:

1. Esta seria a melhor maneira de salvar uma foto?
2. Ref. a qualidade? Temos perda de qualidade na foto?
3. Se for uma foto com alta resolução (ex: 6000x4000 pixel's, 24mb), consigo executar esse processo normalmente?
4. Qualquer tipo de imagem funciona? (Jpeg, PNG, BitMap e outros?)
5. O processo ao contrário, ou seja, pegar o `array` de `Byte` e converter em foto, não seria um processo lento?

Obrigado.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thomas, sugiro que declare a coluna que irá armazenar a imagem da foto como varbinary(max). É que o tipo de dados `image` será desativado (algum dia...), conforme a Microsoft.

Caso o tamanho médio das imagens seja de 1 MB ou mais, a Microsoft sugere que se utilize [FILESTREAM](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/gg471497.aspx) para armazenamento das imagens. Nesse caso, os arquivos de cada imagem não ficam dentro do banco de dados, mas sim no sistema de arquivos do Windows. Isto melhora a performance do gerenciador, considerando-se alocação de memória. Você pode acessar os arquivos usando transações Transact-SQL ou usando API do Win32.

Sugestão de leitura:

- [Habilitar e configurar FILESTREAM](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/cc645923.aspx)
- [Criar um banco de dados habilitado para FILESTREAM](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/cc645585.aspx)
- [Criar uma tabela para armazenar dados FILESTREAM](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/cc645583.aspx)
- [Acessar dados FILESTREAM com Transact-SQL](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/cc645962.aspx)
- [Criar aplicativos clientes para dados FILESTREAM](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/cc645940.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

***1-Este seria a melhor maneira de salvar uma foto?***

Eu prefiro, pois estando no banco de dados, fica acessível em qualquer ambiente (local ou remoto / aplicação ou web), e elimina-se o problema de controlar 2 backups.

***2-Ref. a qualidade? temos perca de qualidade na foto?***

Não, a menos que que você utilize compactação no meio do algoritmo.

***3-Se for uma foto com alta resolução (ex: 6000x4000 pixel's, 24mb), consigo executar esse processo normalmente?***

Sim. Pode ser que fique lento pelo tamanho do arquivo, mas procure usar threads diferentes para carregar a imagem para a aplicação não travar durante o carregamento.
Se ocorrer erros durante o Select, que pode ser por falta de memória ou timeout, o SGDB terá configurações para contornar a situação.

***4-Qualquer tipo de imagem funciona? (Jpge, PNG, BitMap e outros?)***

Acredito que sim, não posso te falar com certeza sobre o tipo "image" do sql server, mas deve ser baseado no VARBINARY. Em outro campo da tabela, grave a extenção do arquivo, aí quando o usuário for salvar, já salva no formato correto. Obs: O VARBINARY você pode salvar qualquer tipo de arquivo: EXE, DLL, ZIP, etc.

***5-O processo ao contrario, ou seja, pegar o array de Byte e converter em foto, não seria um processo lento?***

Depende do tamanho do array, mas só vai perceber lentidão se for absurdamente grande.

Eu prefiro por sempre guardar as imagens no banco, e ao dar o select, eu não busco a coluna da imagem. Ao carregar as informações na tela, exibo um progresso "Carregando imagem" e abro a thread que irá dar o select nesse campo. O mesmo faço para arquivos.

No caso das imagens, segue exemplo das funções que utilizo:

byte[] para Image

```
    public static Image ConvertByteToImage(byte[] pic)
    {
        if (pic != null)
        {
            try
            {
                MemoryStream ImageDataStream = new MemoryStream();
                ImageDataStream.Write(pic, 0, pic.Length);
                System.Drawing.Image img = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(ImageDataStream,true);
                return img;
            }
            catch
            {
                return null;
            }

        }
        else return null;
    }
```

Image para byte[]

```
public static byte[] ConvertImageToByte(System.Drawing.Image foto, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat format )
        {
            if (foto != null)
            {
                using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    foto.Save(stream, format);
                    //stream.Flush();
                    byte[] pic = stream.ToArray();
                    return pic;
                }
            }
            else return null;
        }
```

Comment: A sugestão de acrescentar coluna indicando o tipo de arquivo é fundamental, principalmente para aqueles tipos de imagens que não possuem _header_.