# Como faço para salvar uma imagem no banco de dados através de uma aplicação?

Tags: c#, banco-de-dados, sql-server, imagem, aplicação-desktop

Tenho uma aplicação em c# e quero fazer com que seja possível salvar uma foto no banco de dados SQL. 
1- Como monto a estrutura do banco de dados para receber uma imagem?
2- Como enviarei a foto da aplicação para o BD?

Comment: ou: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/202996/69359

Answer (score 1):

Eu recomendaria salvar a foto em algum diretório do projeto ou algum ftp.

Depois salvar o caminho daquela foto no banco, recentemente fiz isso. Qualquer duvida só perguntar

```
                        //pega o objeto imagem do input front-end
                        HttpPostedFileBase foto = Request.Files["Imagem"];

                        // pega o nome do arquivo
                        var nomeArquivo = Path.GetFileName(foto.FileName);

                        //cria o caminho final da imagem
                        var caminho = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath(Url.Content("~/assets/{nomedapasta}/")), nomeArquivo);

                        //salva a foto no caminho
                        foto.SaveAs(caminho);

                        //imagem do projeto criado recebe o caminho da imagem salva
                        project.Imagem = Path.Combine(Url.Content("/assets/{nomedapasta}/"), nomeArquivo);
```